# How to display 2 elements side by side and have a label display underneath 1 element in react

Tags: html, css

So I currently have a part of my form which contains an input field and a select menu and I want both of these elements to be displayed side by side and then there be a label or paragraph text directly underneath the input field. I am struggling to achieve this layout as the label either shows up in the same row as the 2 elements or it appears centered underneath them from what I have tried. I have attached 2 images one with my current output and one with my desired output

here is the current code and styles I am using vanilla css with react, any advise on my current approach to the styles is also appreciated if I am not going about it the correct way please let me know

current output label is `Last` -> [image]

desired output label is `(Example Jr - Sr)` -> [image]

component:

```
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}> {/* Apply background color to this div */}
        <div className='container'>
          <div className="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg shadow-md">
            <div className="flex justify-between items-center mb-6"> {/* Flex container to align items */}
              <button className="back-btn" onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>&lt;</button>
              
              <h4 className="text-2xl font-semibold ml-4 mb-0 medallionHeading">Create new profile</h4> {/* Add left margin */}
            </div>
            <div className='flex items-center mb-6 border-bottom'>
              <p>Personal Details</p>
            </div>
            <div className='flex items-center info-para'>
              <p className="mb-4 ">Start by entering as much info as you can </p>
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={handleCreateMedallion} encType='multipart/form-data'>
              <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-3 gap-4 mb-4">
                <input className="border p-2 name-inputs" type="text" name="firstName"  required onChange={handleMedallionInputChange} placeholder='First Name: *' />
                <input className="border p-2 name-inputs" type="text" name="middleName"  onChange={handleMedallionInputChange} placeholder="Middle name:" />
                <input className="border p-2 name-inputs" type="text" name="lastName" required onChange={handleMedallionInputChange} placeholder='Last Name: *' />
              </div>
      {/* First row with input and select side by side */}
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-3 gap-4 mb-4">
  
        <input className="title-and-relationship-inputs" type="text" name="ln" id="" />
        <label for="ln">Last</label>

      
        <select className="border p-2 title-and-relationship-inputs">
          <option>-- Relationship Select an option --</option>
        </select>
      
      </div>
           
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
```

styles:

```
.flex.items-center {
    display: flex;
    /* Use flexbox */
}

.centered-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.back-btn {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.medallionHeading {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    /* Add left margin */
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem; /* top, right, bottom, left*/
}

.info-para {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.name-inputs {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0.25rem;
}

.title-and-relationship-inputs {
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0.25rem;
}

.label-below {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #888;
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  display: block;

}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.checkbox-label {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    /* Adjust the margin as needed */
}
```

Comment: *Pun intended:* This is the literal definition of *counterfeiting*. I’ve added the `HTML` tag. You’ll get more help soon.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon how is wanting to achieve a similar design for a section of a form counterfeiting?

Comment: *pun intended*. The current state of the process is what’s funny.

Answer (score 0):

Adding fields in two separate "divs" is better and style them. Like:

```
<div>
    <input className="title-and-relationship-inputs" type="text" name="ln" id="" />
    <label for="ln">Last</label>
</div>
<div>
    <select className="border p-2 title-and-relationship-inputs">
        <option>--
            Relationship Select an option --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you can use the CSS flex property to adjust the output label position. Like:

```
    <div classname="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-3 gap-4 mb-4" style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;column-gap: 20px;">
            <input classname="title-and-relationship-inputs" type="text" name="ln" id="" style="order: 1;">
<label for="ln" style="width: 100%;order: 3;">Last</label>
<select classname="border p-2 title-and-relationship-inputs" style="order: 2;">option>-- Relationship Select an option --</option>
            </select>         
 </div>
```

Hope this will help you.